# Armature not the deforming the mesh symmetrically?

Tags: particles, armature

I've used the Q&As here a lot to help me through the rough start with blender and I'm always grateful for your help. I've hit a wall. Can't find an answer myself, not here by searching, nor anywhere really.

I have a female mesh that is placed centered on the world origin with all transformations applied.
That mesh is symmetrical, with no active mirror modifier.

The metarig (Pitchypoi rigify) is setup symmetrically (used x mirror at first, then symmetrized it, reset the bone roll and applied all tranformations).

The eyelashes are "growing" out of small skin-patch particle emitters.

The particle emitters are snugly placed on the eyelids of the mesh and are set to invisible.

The eyelash emitters are all separate meshes, there are 4 of them, two identical pairs. A pair of upper and a pair of lower lashes (Shift+D, Ctrl+M then X for X axis mirror, then applied all transformations).

The emitters are parented to the rig (auto-generated by addon-script) with automatic weights.
The armature modifier is set Above the Particle in all meshes.

The issue is that when I move the eye control bone the Right-Hand (Left side of pic) moves perfectly fine. The eyelashes move with the lids and the emitter, all in perfect sync, they stick together and work wonderfully... while the Left-hand (Right side of pic) emitter and particles seem to have a greater amplitude of movement, they detach, and float around even though the body mesh (the lids) deforms symmetrically on both sides.
I can only assume that it's a weight issue but I can't locate it. It's all auto generated on identical and symmetrical meshes with one side working and the other not...

I've tried moving the eye control bone up via G then Z, straight up the Z axis, in order to avoid any asymmetry and view the problem in Front Orthographic. What I got is attached below:

[image]

The floating emitter is highlighted in yellow. If anyone has any idea where I could look for the reason why one emitter stays in place while its copy floats around with a greater motion amplitude I'd be very grateful

Edit: Blender version 2.82a. But the same file causes the same issue in 2.83 LTS. The LTS version takes a longer time to save so I use 2.82a.

Edit 2: I've tried "breaking" the other side by deleting the working emitters and duplicating the "broken" ones. I've symmetrized the mesh and metarig from the broken side to the working one too. I've tried new emitters altogether. But the problem remains only on one side (-x side or the Right side if you look at it from the POV in the screen shot). So duplicating the issue to the working side... Seems impossible.

I can't fix the problem nor recreate it on the other side.

Edit 3: I managed to get it to work on the broken side by converting the hair particles into a mesh but this is very undesirable because:

1. The mesh hair causes a drop in performance (increases RAM consumption and even though I have 32 gb, I still don't want to cause unnecessary loads).
2. It does not accept the material (instead always displaying the new mesh-strands as pitch black).
3. It is still inferior to the particle system that does deform properly. Some strands seem to be randomly floating away and deforming counter-intuitively (See 2nd attached screenshot).

[image]

Does that mean it's a bug in the software itself? I have not changed anything except converting the particles into a mesh. Same rig, same meshes, same weights... If I parent the particle system AND the new mesh system together: the particle one still floats around when I move the bones that govern it...

Edit 4:
I've tried cutting the mesh in half and mirroring the other half. Same issue persisted.

I've also tried mirroring the metarig. The issue persisted.

Note: On a side note I'd also like to ask why in viewport shading light does not penetrate into the mesh while in Eevee render preview it does (cavities and orifices have light in them)? I know I've ticked something but idk what.

Thanks!